# Access library initiated in constructor function in function

Tags: php, function

I just got help with how to access a function in a function. Now Im trying from the inside function reach a library which is intitade in the constructor.

My code look like this:

```
<?php
class Test_model extends CI_Model 
{
    private $ci;

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        // Initiate instance
        $ci =& get_instance();

        // Load helper
        $ci->load->helper('text');
    }

    public function check()
    {
        echo $this->uniqueString();
    }

    public function uniqueString($unique = FALSE)
    {
        function random()
        {
            return parent::random_string('alnum',20);
        }

        while($unique === FALSE)
        {
            $random = random();

            $this->db->where('ver_code', $random);
            $this->db->from('user');

            if($this->db->count_all_results() == 0)
            {
                return $random;
                $unique = TRUE;
            }
        }
    }


}
?>
```

But I'm not able to reach the library helper from the function random. I have tried

```
parent::random_string('alnum',20);
$ci->random_string('alnum',20);
$this->ci->random_string('alnum',20);
random_string('alnum',20);
```

I get errors like:

```
Call to undefined method Test_model::random_string()
Cannot access self:: when no class scope is active in
Using $this when not in object context in
```

How is the right way to do it?

Comment: Right way is not to use the approach you have. What's the point of having an anonymous function there? Anyway, if it's for learning purposes - you'd pass a parameter to your `random()` function which would be the current object ($this). Then your `random` function would have access to your class methods (public ones). Then you'd create a method that would invoke `parent::` which you would call from within your `random` function. As you can see - things get messy pretty fast, and when they do - that's a sign of bad approach.

Comment: Thanks that got me in the right direction. Thats true totaly unnecessary to have the anonymous function there.